# create a secondary menu with mmenu

Tags: jquery, html, mmenu

this is my problem:
I have in my website a hamburger-menu icon which is linked to the main menu. Next to the hambuger-menu icon there is a user icon which I want to be linked to another menu. That secondary menu will have the same style as the main menu, but another content (A sign in / log in form).
Is there any way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are using mmenu, then any menu you do will have the same style as the basic light grey one, unless you're using the themes extension. Are you using mmenu?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are using, or want to use mmenu JS.
first download the CSS and JS files [here](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/download.html).

**Include the CSS and JS in your project.**

1. In your downloads folder, go to **jQuery.mmenu-master\dist**. Inside the CSS folder is **jquery.mmenu.all** file. add it to your project.
2. Inside the JS folder is **jquery.mmenu.all.min** file. add it to your project. 
   You can read through the sites tutorial and see what all the other files are for, but this is enough to get you started.
3. You should include the latest [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) file in your project as well.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
       <link href="CSS/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
       <script src="JS/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>    
   </head>
   ```
4. inside the `<body>` tag create another `<div>` tag.

   ```
   <body>
       <div>
       </div>
   </body>
   ```
5. Inside the `<div>` create you two menus. Put menu items inside a list.

   ```
   <a href="#menu1">Hamburger-icon</a>
   <a href="#menu2">User-icon</a>

   <nav id="menu1">
       <div>
           <ul>
               <li>item1</li>
               <li>item2</li>
           </ul>           
       </div>    
   </nav>
   <nav id="menu2">
       <div>
           <ul>
               <li>item1</li>
               <li>item2</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </nav>
   ```
6. now add a `<script>` tag underneath the last div, inside the body.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#menu1").mmenu({
               });
               $("#menu2").mmenu({
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

   This code wil create two menus off the page. When the hamburger icon is clicked, menu 1 will open. when user icon is clicked, menu 2 will open. See mmenu tutorial for further tweaks and customization.